# Editar registros ligados a un ID con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo un programa cotizador, CON PHP y MySQL. Usando $_SESSION, me guarda la información de la descripción del producto, costo unitario, cantidades, importe, etc y me lo separa en dos tablas, unidas a un "ID de cotización" en la BDD. Puedo consultar la información con el ID_Cotizacion, mostrarlo en pantalla para poder editar esa información y hasta aqui todo bien.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['upd'])){
    $id = $_GET['upd'];
    // $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM presupuestos p INNER JOIN clientes c ON p.cliente_id = c.id_cliente WHERE id_presupuesto = $id;");
    $sentencia = $pdo-> prepare("SELECT * FROM presupuestos p
                                INNER JOIN presupuestos_partidas pp
                                ON p.id_presupuesto = pp.presupuesto_id
                                INNER JOIN clientes c
                                ON p.cliente_id = c.id_cliente
                                WHERE id_presupuesto = $id");
    $sentencia->execute();
    $presupuestos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
```

Para editar la informacion, asigno los campos a variables y luego las mando llamar en los values de los inputs text.

```
<form action="upd.php" method="POST">

<?php foreach ($presupuestos as $presupuesto): ?>
<td width="5%">
    <input type="text" id="partida" name="partida" 
    value="<?php echo $presupuesto['partida']; ?>" class="form-ontrol">
</td>
<td width="50%" style="text-align: justify;">
    <input type="text" name="descripcion" style="width: 100%;"
    value="<?php echo $presupuesto['descripcion'] ;?>">
</td>
<td width="5%">
    <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" style="width: 
    100%; text-align: center;"
    value="<?php echo $presupuesto['cantidad'] ;?>">
</td>
<td width="15%">
    <span>$</span><input type="text" id="precio_unitario" 
    name="precio_unitario" style="width: 50%; text-align: center;"
    value="<?php echo number_format($presupuesto['precio_unitario'],2) ;?>">
</td>
<td class="text-center" width="15%"><span>$</span>
    <input type="text" style="width: 80%;" id="importe" name="importe"
    value="<?php  echo number_format($presupuesto['cantidad'] * $presupuesto['precio_unitario'],2); ?>">
</td>
    <td width="15%"><form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="partida" value="">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="btnAccion" 
    value="Eliminar">Eliminar</button>
</td>

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="btnAccion" value="Actualizar">Actualizar</button>
```

y pues me muestra la información, disponible para editar, incluso cuando se tiene mas de un producto. Pero al momento de enviar la informacion por POST, al revisar en la pagina destino con "print_r($_POST), solo me muestra un "producto", cuando esa cotizacion, tiene mas de 1 "producto"

```
    Array
(
    [partida] => 
    [descripcion] => ESCALERAS CON PTR SOLDADA
    [cantidad] => 2
    [precio_unitario] => 1,500.00
    [importe] => 3,000.00
    [materiales] => 2760
    [manobra] => 1840
    [subTotal] => 4600
    [iva] => 368
    [total] => 4968
    [btnAccion] => Actualizar
)
```

Comment: Y como  lo estaras mostrando...

Comment: Uso INNER JOINS, para poder tener acceso a los campos de ambas tablas y asignarles el nombre de los campos a variables, para luego ponerlas en los values de los inputs text y hasta ahi todo bien, pero al momento de enviar esa información editada por POST, en aquellas cotizaciones con mas de 1 producto, solo me muestra el ultimo registro.  uso un ciclo foreach, para que me recorra toda la cotización. espero haberme dado a entender jejejejeje

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No. y si no mostrar el codigo de las cosas involucradas, es imposible saber que estas haciendo mal...

Comment: Una disculpa, es que es la primera vez que hago una pregunta. puse el código. Muchas gracias por el interés.

Comment: Si en una sola cotización hay varios productos y quieres que en un solo formulario se envíen varios productos, el atributo `name` de cada `input` debería tener al final unos corchetes para que los daros se envíen como un arreglo. por ejemplo `name="descripcion[]"`. [esta consulta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=insert+multiple+en+php) en StackOverflow te puede mostrar varios ejemplos.

Comment: Amigo, me funciono, muchisimas gracias. efectivamente con los corchetes, ya me respeta toda la información y me los envía por POST, aunque sigue sin aparecerme el del name="partida[]" o numero de linea, al revisar el POST, no me aparece ese dato, pero creo que se dato no me dara problemas. Muchas gracias

Comment: Perdón, ya me aparecen todos los datos enviados por POST, no habia puesto atención, pero te puedo confirmar que con la solución de los corchetes, ya recibo los datos por POST. Muchas gracias,